How do I save the data on an unmountable disk?
Environment
Ubuntu 20.04
I made a back up before moving into Ubuntu on an external disk that was working (working on 3 different computers, with Linux Mint, Windows 10 and Ubuntu).
While I was copying back the backup I got a crash, so I had to restart the computer.
To my surprise, when I tried to see what happened to the files, I got this message when double click on Seagate Basic to open the disk (i dont know other ways to mount it):

I tried the same external disk on a Linux Mint laptop I had around and got kind of the same message as a result.
Since its a problem happening in both two different computers, i guess something happened to the external disk (maybe corrupt?).
How can I go deeper in the problem to fix it?
And how can I keep the information in this disk?
I actually don't know how to provide more information about the problem and what I should write. Please help me to explain better :)
Edit 1:
I ran this:
lucas@lucas-GF63:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for lucas:
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdb1 was processed successfully.
So i guess its a NTFS partition.

This question is similar to: sda1 unmountable and (probably) corrupt. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Does the device also not mount on Windows?  If not, then the drive is probably corrupt and data is not easily salvageable

I currently dont have a Windows computer to try.

Ask a friend with Windows computer. Microsoft created NTFS. Their software may fix more problems with NTFS than any open source alternatives. If Windows can't fix NTFS then nothing can. I'm future format external drives partitionsas ext4 for backing up/copying data to and from Linux.

I solved it, not pretty much sure how (anyone can explain tho)
I ran these lines:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sdb1

Goot to hear. You may answer your own question, and accept it after a bit, helping others and gaining some reputation points in the process.
